# String word count without using regex?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to figure out an effective way to do a word count for a given string in JavaScript, without the use of regex.

The following works for some strings:

```
function wordCount(str) { 
  return str.split(" ").length;
}

console.log(wordCount("howdy there partner"));
```

However - when given a string like, " this is an example " the word count goes to 6 instead of 4. Additionally, this approach will not work for empty strings, like "" or " " (will return a word count of 1 and 2, respectively).

**Is there any way to do an accurate word count for these instances, without the use of regex?**

Comment: You can use trim() to remove spaces from front and last, and also you can put condition for empty strings.  https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=RxBlfOSizz

Comment: By "without the use of regex", are you referring to regexp as an alternative to split, or the use of a regex as an argument to split?

Comment: @torazaburo As an argument to split

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. By the way, why this restriction?

Comment: @torazaburo I'm not really comfortable with using regex at the moment, so I was curious to see if there was a way I could accomplish this task without it. Will probably tackle it sometime in the near future.

Comment: Instead of making people answering jump through hoops due to your own comfort level in an area which is very much a core feature of the language, you should remove the restriction, let people propose non-crippled solutions, and use those as the starting point for your regexp learning process, and by the way, the regexps useful here are not rocket science by any means.

Comment: @torazaburo Understood, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out blank values:

```
function wordCount(str) {
    return str.split(' ').filter(function(val){ return val != '' }).length
}
```

Comment: Or `filter(Boolean)`. Also, with the filter, do you really need the `trim`? Finally, wouldn't `split(/\s+/)` be better?

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to relax your limitation on using regexp, you can do this directly, without using `split`:

```
sentence.match(/\w+/g).length
```

This means match any sequence of characters (`\w`) with a length of one or more (`+`), globally (`g`). It will return an array of matches, the length of which will give the number of words.

In order to protect against the case where there are no words in the string, and `match` will return `null`, you should actually write:

```
(sentence.match(/\w+/g) || []).length
```

which is still a few characters shorter than the alternative

```
sentence.split(' ').filter(Boolean).length
```

in case you worry about such things.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wordCount(str) { 
  return str.trim().split(" ").length;
}

console.log(wordCount("howdy there partner"));
```

Comment: This will fail if the words are separated by more than one space.